# Displaying the fields next to each other

Tags: apex, visualforce

EDIT:

The other option is to use `style='position: relative; left: 50%;'` adjust the `%` but this will not render correctly if the user tries to have a different resoultion on the screen.

As a sample this is what I'm trying to put `from/to date` in my page, look for the red box:

[image]

END EDIT:

How can I make the 'From/To Invoice Date`align to`Employee Name` label?

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Page" columns="2" id="pbs">
        ............
        ............
     <apex:outputPanel >
     <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2"> 
          <apex:inputField value="{!obj.InvDate__c}" label="From: Invoice Date" />
          <br/><apex:inputField value="{!obj.InvDate__c}" label="To: Invoice Date" />
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use the concept of Padding in CSS

Comment: In the page block section item wrap a tabled in an output panel. ie. `<apex:pageblocksectionitem><apex:outputpanel><table>.....</table></apex:outputPanel></apex:pageblocksectionitem>` - There can only be one root element in a section item so wrap it in an output panel. the table allows you to position properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright finally found a way to do that, hope this will help others enjoy!

Using [apex:panelGrid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_panelGrid.htm)

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">  
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.Department}"/>   
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel value="Invoice Date"/>
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
            <apex:inputfield value="{!obj.InvDate__c}" id="invfrom" html-placeholder="From Invoice Date"/>
            <br></br> 
            <apex:inputfield value="{!obj.InvDate__c}" id="invto" html-placeholder="To Invoice Date"/>
        </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Glad you got it. Essentially what's in my comment I just use a table more than I do a panel grid. Thanks for posting your solution

Answer (score 0):

use  for all fields

or you can use simple table td tr of html.

If i will design this page i will use table

for every row and column